# Module not found: Can't resolve './.htaccss' after installing React-boilerplate Dandelion starter project

Tags: reactjs, react-boilerplate, dandelion

I have downloaded Dandelion starter-project and decompressed it on a local folder. I ran:

```
npm i
npm run build:dll
```

and then

```
npm start
```

then it complains:

```
> dandelion_pro@1.6.1 start /home/......./dandelion/starter-project
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server

Happy[js]: Version: 5.0.1. Threads: 5 (shared pool)
Server started ! ✓

Access URLs:
-----------------------------------
Localhost: http://localhost:3001
      LAN: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3001
-----------------------------------
Press CTRL-C to stop
Webpack is building script...

Happy[js]: All set; signaling webpack to proceed.
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `yarn upgrade`
webpack built 920e70412c607c0d50a6 in 3600ms
✖ ｢wdm｣: 
ERROR in ./app/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './.htaccess' in '/home/......./dandelion/starter-project/app'
 @ ./app/app.js 27:0-48
 @ multi ./node_modules/react-app-polyfill/ie11.js webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true ./app/app.js
```

I have searched the web looking for a solution, but I was unable to find one. My system is a Ubuntu 18.04.3 based machine running Linux Mint 19.3, nodejs 12.15.0 and npm 6.13.4. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well folks after an endless unsuccessful search on the web I created an empty ´.htaccess´ file and placed it into the ´app´ folder. Maybe this is not the better or the elegantest way to do it, but it worked for me.

I am posting this hoping it might be helpful.